# minimal vertex cover and P=NP

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, computational-complexity, computability, turing-machines

could someone please explain to me why the following occurs?

let function f be a function that finds the minimal vertex cover. meaning: f(G,v)=minimal vertex cover that v belongs to

(the graph is indirected and no weights involved)

why if we know that f can be calculated in polynomial time then P=NP?

how do i prove such thing? i write because given f runs in polynomial time than P=NP?

i know that vertex cover is a NP-Hard(even NP-Complete). so how to write a proof? i just say since vertex cover is np complete, and minimal vertex cover is basically $min{f(x):x\in vertexcover(G)}$, then since i know it runs in polynomial time it means P=NP?

edit: from what i understand, the question is about reducing vertex cover to minimal vertex cover. since vertex cover is np-complete, then if it computes in polynomial time, then minimal vertex cover should also be computed in polynomial time. my problem is that reduction, i am not sure how to do it, how to do the reduction correctly.

would really appreciate to see how such a proof would look like to know what to aspire to in similar problems

thanks a lot

Comment: P is the class of all Problems that can be solved in polynomial time, NP is the class of all Problems that can be verified in polynomial time. So it's clear that $P \subset NP$. A subclass of NP are the NP complete problems, so to speak the hardest Problems in NP. They all can be reduced to the same Problem, so they are, in a way, the same problem. If one can solve one of these in polynomial time, then we can solve all of them in polynomial time.

Comment: but how to do it, that's what i have been asking in this post, this proof, this is my problem and i am not able to get it

Comment: Just search for it on google, you are getting a lot of examples where one problem in NP is reduced to another one.

Comment: If you mean the proof, that all of them can be solved in polynomial time if one can be solved in polynomial time, that's fairly easy. You just use the reduction and are done.

Comment: this is what i mean, but i can't think of a reduction/algorithm that gets it done. this is what i've been asking

Comment: It's extremely hard to reduce one such problem to another. You need lots of experience and a huge arsenal of other reductions. You can't just start thinking of some reduction unless you're a huge genious. Maybe try first starting with some reductions to 3SAT.

Comment: If you have a Boolean formula in [conjunctive normal form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunctive_normal_form) consider every variable to be a vertex. Then every time there is $x\vee y$ in the formula, even if it appears in a big disjuction $x\vee x_1\vee...\vee y$, you add an edge connecting the vertices for $x$ and $y$. Note that a vertex cover, tells you a way to assign Boolean values to the formula such that it is satisfied. [Here](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~jan/mcs401/reductions.pdf) you can find some other reductions.

Comment: assuming i already showed vertex cover to be NP-Complete, then can't i use some kind of verifier in the algorithm to make it easier to do the reduction?

Comment: As far as I know the vertex cover problem is the same as the minimum  vertex cover problem.  See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vertex-cover-problem-set-1-introduction-approximate-algorithm-2/, for example.  What are you calling the vertex cover problem?

Answer (score 0):

The class of NP-complete problems has a special property which has been proven :

> If one problem can be solved in polynomial time, then all of them can be solved in polynomial time.

There must be a polynomial transformation from one problem to another in this class, but I am not aware of any details.

So, if you actually would find a polynomial algorithm for an NP-complete problem, you will become famous and rich.

Comment: how can i prove what's given in the question? this is my problem

Comment: Sorry, I am not aware of how the proof works either. Probably, it is difficult to prove the property.

Comment: isn't it all about showing a reduction from vertex cover to minimal vertex cover? since the first is np complete, so if it is computed in polynomial time, the latter (minimal vertex cover) should be computed in polynomial time. i don't know how to get that reduction. or am i missing something bigger?